# php graph api multi page access user object - canvas app

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api

I have several pages in my `canvas app` and from `page-a` the user logs into oAuth then gets directed to `page-b` which has the code below.
When i login oAuth using javascript api i can get full access to the user object. 
But then when i go to another page, the code below gives an error. 
The `token` echo's out but `getUser` does not.
It looks like `$user = $facebook->getUser();` never gets called, or as `CBroe` pointed out, it prob. returns 0

Is there a way to have just the php access `user object` without javascripts api so that i can traverse page to page?

```
require_once('/facebook-php-sdk-3.1.1-25-6c82b3f/src/facebook.php');
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
    'appId'  => '<MY-APP-ID>',
    'secret' => '<MY-APP-SECRET>'
));

// Get User ID
$user = $facebook->getUser();
$token = $facebook->getAccessToken();

if ($user) {
    try {
        $facebook->setFileUploadSupport(true);

        $fbUser = $facebook->api('/me');

    } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
        error_log($e);
        $user = null;
    }
}

/*      **          **          **
Undefined variable: fbUser 
**          **          **          */

//print_r($fbUser); 
echo $fbUser['id']; 
echo '<br/>';
echo $fbUser['name'];
```

Comment: "But then when i go to another page, the code below gives an error."  What's the error?

Comment: @Lee i think CBroe nailed it, its prob. returning a 0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It looks like $user = $facebook->getUser(); never gets called

What makes you think that? [1]

There’s nothing in that snippet of code that would prevent it from being executed – much more likely, that it just returns 0 because it does not recognize the user. And that usually points to problems with passing the session id, often caused by the browser rejecting third party cookies.

---

[1] Debugging is about **verifying** stuff by checking what your code actually does, and not just *guessing* in a “it looks like” manner.

Comment: thank you CBroe,  but why would it return a 0 when the previous page outputs all the correct info?  I would like to debug, can you give some pointers please.

Comment: Like I said, problems with the PHP session not picked up again due to the session id not getting passed because the client rejected cookies is one of the most common reasons for this kind of error.